# Drawing circular arcs of 60 degrees in `TikZ`

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw circular arcs at two angles of measure 60 degrees. Why don't

```
\draw[draw=green] ($(B')!0.375cm!(A')$) arc (180:120:0.375);
\draw[draw=blue] ($(P')!3.75mm!(B')$) arc (0:60:0.375);
```

render circular arcs? `A'`, `P'`, and `B'` are all points on a horizontal line.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm, y=0.3cm]

\path let \n1={6.5*(sqrt(3)/2)} in (0,0) coordinate (A) (10,0) coordinate (B) (6.75,\n1) coordinate (C) (3.25,\n1) coordinate (D);
\path[fill=LimeGreen!75] (A) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\path[fill=LimeGreen!75] (B) -- (C) -- (6.75,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=NavyBlue!50] (A) -- (C) -- (6.75,0) -- cycle;
\draw[OliveGreen] (A) -- (D) -- (C);
\draw[OliveGreen] (B) -- (C) -- (6.75,0);
\draw[OliveGreen] (B) -- (6.75,0);
\draw[blue] (A) -- (C);
\draw[blue] (A) -- (6.75,0);
\draw[dashed, thick, yellow] (6.75,0) -- (C);



%An arrow from the given isosceles trapezoid to a decomposition of it into a parallelogram and two congruent right triangles.
\draw[-latex] let \n1={6.5*(sqrt(3)/2)/2} in (11,\n1) to[out=60,in=120] (13,\n1);



\path let \n1={6.5*(sqrt(3)/2)} in (14,0) coordinate (A') (24,0) coordinate (B') (20.75,\n1) coordinate (C') (17.25,\n1) coordinate (D')
(17.5,0) coordinate (P');
\draw[OliveGreen] (A') -- (D') -- (C');
\draw[OliveGreen] (B') -- (C') -- (17.5,0);
\draw[OliveGreen] (B') -- (20.75,0);
\path[fill=LimeGreen!75] (A') -- (C') -- (D') -- cycle;
\path[fill=NavyBlue!50] (A') -- (C') -- (P') -- cycle;
\draw[blue] (A') -- (20.75,0);
\draw[blue, dashed] (C') -- (P');
\draw[blue] (A') -- (C');



%The legs of the isosceles trapezoid and BP are marked with "|".
\draw[OliveGreen, thick] ($($(A')!0.5!(D')$)!3pt!90:(A')$) -- ($($(A')!0.5!(D')$)!3pt!-90:(A')$);
\draw[OliveGreen, thick] ($($(B')!0.5!(C')$)!3pt!90:(B')$) -- ($($(B')!0.5!(C')$)!3pt!-90:(B')$);
\draw[blue, thick] ($($(C')!0.5!(P')$)!3pt!90:(C')$) -- ($($(C')!0.5!(P')$)!3pt!-90:(C')$);
\draw[dashed, thick, yellow] (20.75,0) -- (C');



%The marks indicating the measure of \angle{ABC} and \angle{BPC} are drawn. Since they are congruent to each other, they are marked with "|".
\draw[draw=green] ($(B')!0.375cm!(A')$) arc (180:120:0.375);
\draw[draw=green] ($(B') +(150:{0.375cm-3pt})$) -- ($(B') +(150:{0.375cm+3pt})$);
%
\draw[draw=blue] ($(P')!3.75mm!(B')$) arc (0:60:0.375);
\draw[draw=blue] ($(P') +(30:{0.375cm-3pt})$) -- ($(P') +(30:{0.375cm+3pt})$);



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: On my computer they do produce circular arcs. Unfortunately your document is such that the figure is too wide and the nice arcs get clipped away.

Comment: @marmot  I am not sure what you mean by "figure is too wide."  The two trapezoids are centered on the page with lots of horizontal space to the left and right of it.

Comment: @marmot If I were to issue `\draw[draw=green] (B) circle (1);`, `TikZ` would draw a circle of radius `1cm` about `B` - as expected. Why isn't it working with an `arc` command?

Comment: On my just updated TeXLive 2019 distribution when compiled with either `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` most of the right trapezoid gets cut away. If I either remove the left one or use the `standalone` class, the arcs show. The nondeprecated syntax is `arc[start angle=...,end angle=...,radius=...]` but this does not make a difference here.

Comment: This is bizarre. Why are the `arc` commands the only commands in this code that are not properly implemented?

Comment: I just hope that someone else will have a look at this. Since I am very confident that my TeX installation works, for me the most likely explanations are (i) you compile a different code than the above or (ii) something is wrong with your TeX installation.

Comment: My `TeX` installation is probably faulty. While waiting for responses to this post, I was going to edit a file that I have had for years. It kept giving me error messages. I deleted more and more code ... until there was nothing remaining except the preamble. It still would not compile!

Comment: I just tried the same code on a different computer. I get the same image.

Comment: Which image do you get, exactly? Are there any messages in the log file? I'm still on TL18, and like @marmot I get a diagram that is wider than the page so most of the right hand side trapezoid is cut off. (No surprise, the entire diagram is 24cm wide...) And if I change to the `standalone` class I see that the two arcs are rendered perfectly fine. (Screenshots at https://imgur.com/a/gLlY5n4).

Comment: Add the options `x=0.3cm, y=0.3cm` to the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: This is so stupid - I edited my code replacing `(10,0) coordinate (B)` with `({(3/10)*10},0) coordinate (B)` and making similar modifications with the other coordinates ... and I get exactly what I want!

Comment: Please use `@<username>` when replying to specific users, otherwise they won't be notified (only the user who wrote the question/answer is notified of all comments). Also, I suggest you edit the code in your question and add `[x=0.3cm, y=0.3cm]`, so that the question actually makes sense. I do get misplaced arcs when adding those options.

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I had been getting curves starting at the right point but they were not circular arcs and they were only about a tenth of a centimeter long.

Comment: I got https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB2oA.png, which doesn't look like what you're describing. Edit: try `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]`

Comment: @Torbjørn T. That is what I got. They are curves - not circular arcs - that are starting in the right place and only about a tenth of a centimeter long.  (I did add the options `x=0.3cm, y=0.3cm` to the `tikzpicture` environment in my post.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the unit of the `arc` radius:

```
\draw[draw=green] ($(B')!0.375cm!(A')$) arc (180:120:0.375cm);

\draw[draw=blue] ($(P')!3.75mm!(B')$) arc (0:60:0.375cm);
```

[image]

(By the way, what you were seeing are circular arcs, but the radius is smaller.)

Comment: Isn't the default in centimeters?

Comment: Did the options in the `tikzpicture` change the `0.375` in `\draw[draw=green] ($(B')!0.375cm!(A')$) arc (180:120:0.375cm);` to `(3/10)*0.375`?

Comment: Haven't tried figuring out exactly what happens, but could be that if no unit is specified, that it is scaled by the unit vector, so when you change the unit vectors to be 0.3cm instead of 1cm, the radius becomes 0.375*0.3cm.